# jquery rollover image moves out of position (jquery-hover)

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I'm a jquery noob and having trouble with images staying in position.  I have a jquery-hover function that grabs the src attribute of an image and replace it with the value of an attribute called "over".  The actual image replacement works correctly, but the rollover image appears about 10% further down the y-axis whenever the mouseenter event fires.  I'm looking for a complete overlapping "replacement" of one image with another without the rollover image appearing in a different position.  Here's the function:

```
function createRollovers()
{
    var origImg ="";
    $(".swapImage").hover (
    function() {
        origImg = ($(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).attr("src", ($(this).attr("over")));
    },
    function() {
       $(this).attr("src", origImg);
    }
 );
}
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="rightSide">
    <img class="swapImage" over="images/principlesBar_hover.jpg"  src="images/principlesBar.jpg" />
    <img class="swapImage" over="images/processBar_hover.jpg"  src="images/processBar.jpg" />
    <img class="swapImage" over="images/productsBar_hover.jpg"  src="images/productsBar.jpg" />
</div>
```

I'm sure it's something very simple that someone more experienced would see in a heartbeat.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: sounds like your hover image has different dimensions... are they exactly the same size?

Comment: Yes, each image is 180x773px, including each rollover.  I suspect this is more of a CSS problem now, perhaps containers are not sized properly.  Here is the page:

http://test.blackcypresscapital.com/

One of the images' rollover performs correctly.  I think there's a layout problem, but I'll try the alternative Javascript method that enam provided.  I appreciate all your suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need JavaScript/jQuery for this. Try the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class to change the background image of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Ates. But, CSS hover only work for anchor tag in some browser i.e IE6 etc. If you want to implement this with simple JS you can check [this link](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript_image_change_functions.php3)